# What is the shortest way to create an alias that take a parameter?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, alias

I have a command

```
lsof -i :3000
```

When I run it, I got this

```
⚡️lsof -i :3000                                                                                                             
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME                                                              
node    6803 bheng   13u  IPv6 0xa757c4ba1a0bf589      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

I want to create an alias of this command that takes a parameter as my port number.

I'm not looking to create a function or anything just for this.

---

## I've tried

`alias checkport='lsof -i :$1'`

I want to use it like this

```
checkport 3000
```

---

## Result

```
⚡️checkport 3000                                                                                                            
lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i :                                                                                    
lsof 4.89                                                                                                                         
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/                                                                 
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ                                                                   
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man                                                         
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]                                                                   
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]                                                                     
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]                                                     
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

Answer (score 5):

Aliases don't take parameters. Define a function instead.

```
checkport () {
    lsof -i ":$1"
}
```

However, because the "argument" to the alias is simply appended to the end of the alias expansion, you could also define

```
alias checkport='lsof -i :'
```

Both would be used the same way: `checkpoint 3000`.

Comment: Ohh.. how do I use it after define that function ?

Comment: You use functions the same way you would any command: `checkpoint 3000`.

Comment: where is that function should go ? inside a certain file somewhere ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You would define it wherever you were planning to define the alias.

Comment: in the .bash_profile , got it.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is typically a worse choice than `.bashrc`, unless you're `export`ing the function (as with `export -f checkport`). And since you *can't* export an alias, `.bash_profile` is a bad choice for them in general.

Comment: even on a Mac ?

Comment: Also, is the function name much match the alias name ?

Comment: On a Mac, your new terminals will evaluate `.bash_profile`, but that doesn't mean other shells they start will do so as well; whereas *all* interactive bash instances source `.bashrc`.

Comment: "must match the alias name"? Eh? We're advising to use a function *instead of* an alias, not in addition to.

Comment: Where should I add my aliases, so I don't have to open up a new sessions to be able to access those new aliases ?

Comment: For this function: `.bash_profile`, but put `export -f checkport` after the definition.

Comment: I'd put them in `.bashrc` (and don't export) instead of `.bash_profile`; that ensures they get sourced for any interactive shell without wasting space in the environment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do I need to run `export -f checkport` on a cli or need to add it after my function ?

Comment: ...the caveat there is that MacOS is a bit weird, and one might need to `[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc` or such from `.bash_profile` there to get `.bashrc` consistently executed.

Comment: @ihue, bottom line, there are other questions about how to do this, and multiple possible answers with some disagreement -- consider finding such a question and evaluating its answers and their comment threads to make your own decision. :)

Comment: I am very confuse, I don't which one of you, I shold listen too now. :D. Both of you seems very knowledgable about bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I guess, I will do that. Thanks for advise. :)