# Angular - ng b --prod to ng b --configuration=production

Tags: angular-cli

I have just upgraded from Angular 7 to Angular 14.

One of the breaking changes is `ng b --prod` is no longer recognised; instead it is now `ng b --configuration=production`.

Is there any way I can map `ng b --prod` to `ng b --configuration=production`?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the shortest way to create an alias that take a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536155/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-create-an-alias-that-take-a-parameter)

Comment: Long story short:  you want an alias (a way to make one command be another) but you also need to take a parameter, and the only way you can do that is to create a function in your shell dialect of choice.  Alternatively...you could also just modify whatever it is that's running this command to the new parameter instead, which would involve a whole *lot* less gnashing of teeth in this context.

Comment: Hmmm.... I was expecting something to be defined in the `angular.json` file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular so I wouldn't know, but I suppose the next question I have - what is the requirement to do this?  Could you not change whatever you're using to use the new parameter instead?  Why go through the hassle (from an outsider's perspective)?

Comment: Because - out of sheer laziness - it represents more characters to type and also more opportunities for typo. `ng b --prod` is a lot more straightforward.